# Estimation of "CPU", "CPU Load" and "Memory_Usage" for an Android app

Tags: android, performance, memory

We are using Trepn to get the "CPU", "CPU Load" and "Memory_Usage" of some andriod app.
Please see the attached screenshot for the Memory Plot generated in eclipse.

My Question is, though my phone is in idle state, trepn is showing 1.7GB of memory usage. 
Can someone tell us why is it taking that much memory though no other application is launched.

Also, Is there any way to relate this value (1.7GB) to my application to tell if this value is acceptable or it is using more?

We came accross the formulae for calculating memory from trepn site:
Memory Usage = (number of pages the application has in RAM) * (page size) / (total available RAM)
Can some one explain how is this page(s) calculated?

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1778375/find-out-how-many-pages-of-memory-a-process-uses-on-linux

Comment: I don't think that this formula is really used by that software, memory handling on a modern OS is very complex.

Comment: @didierc Is there any process/way to judge how much memory an application can use? So that we can compare that value to the value given by some tool [like trepn].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558402/memory-usage-of-current-process-in-c

Comment: The above is for the current process, but if you have access to the `/proc` directory on android, you could use it for any process.

Comment: Apparently you can: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32373/35-mb-in-proc-folder

Comment: Note that I don't know if this is feasible in Java.